# Запись в файл CSV списка словарей Python разной длины

Tags: python, csv, словари, dict

Имеется список словарей:

```
my_list = [{'color': 'red', 'size':'medium', 'cost': 3000},
           {'color': 'blue', 'cost': 200},
           {'size':'big','color': 'black',  'count': 20, 'active': True}]
```

Как записать данный список словарей в файл CSV так, чтобы все возможные значения ключей были заголовками, значения словарей были строками? При этом нужно распределить значения по столбцам в соответствии со значением ключа. В ячейках, для стобцов которых в словаре нет ключа необходимо оставить пустое значение.

Answer (score 2):

Для удобства записи словарей в CSV в Python есть [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). Но перед его использованием нужно будет получить набор всех уникальных ключей словарей.

```
import csv


my_list = [{'color': 'red', 'size':'medium', 'cost': 3000},
           {'color': 'blue', 'cost': 200},
           {'size':'big','color': 'black',  'count': 20, 'active': True}]

# Получаем набор заголовков
columns = set(i for d in my_list for i in d)
# {'active', 'color', 'cost', 'count', 'size'}

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=columns)
    writer.writeheader() # Пишем заголовок
    for row in my_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если количество заголовков неизвестно заранее, можно так:

```
my_list = [{'color': 'red', 'size':'medium', 'cost': 3000},{'color': 'blue', 'cost': 200},{'size':'big','color': 'black',  'count': 20, 'active': True}]

set_columns = set()
for d in my_list:
    for key in d:
        set_columns.add(key)

for d in my_list:
    for column in set_columns:
        if not column in d:
            d[column] = None

print(my_list) 
# [{'color': 'red', 'size': 'medium', 'cost': 3000, 'active': None, 'count': None},
# {'color': 'blue', 'cost': 200, 'size': None, 'active': None, 'count': None}, 
# {'size': 'big', 'color': 'black', 'count': 20, 'active': True, 'cost': None}]
```